# Rest API return output in different formats

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, content-type, media-type

I have a Rest api that returns list of emailIds given a list of customerIds - **"/v1/customers/ids"**

I need a new endpoint that returns Map of customerId->emailId. Since my resource is same I want to call same endpoint **"v1/customers/ids"**

*I want api to be Restful.*

I followed this article to create a custom media type - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-custom-media-type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ids",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<String> getEmailIdsByCustomerIds(@RequestBody List<String> customerIds) {

        return customerService.getEmailIdsByCustomerIds(customerIds);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ids",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = "application/custIdToEmailId+json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Map<String, String> getCustomerIdToEmailIdMapByCustomerIds(@RequestBody List<String> customerIds) {

        return customerService.getCustomerIdToEmailIdMapByCustomerIds(customerIds);
}
```

When I hit this endpoint using Postman I get - **415 Unsupported Media Type exception**

Answer (score 0):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ids",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = "application/custIdToEmailId+json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Map<String, String> getCustomerIdToEmailIdMapByCustomerIds(@RequestBody List<String> customerIds) {

        return customerService.getCustomerIdToEmailIdMapByCustomerIds(customerIds);
}
```

I am not sure.But try using GET for one of the api